# Setting Java AWS Lambda VM Parameters

Tags: java, jvm, aws-lambda

Is there a way I can configure VM parameters on a Java AWS Lambda? I've already searched the AWS Lambda docs and blogs, and have found no way to configure the underlying system whatsoever.

Comment: With the exception of the memory available to your application I've never seen a way to do this.  What are you trying to set?

Comment: Im trying to set the agentpath for a monitoring tool.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this.  The AWS Lambda environment is very controlled and the VM may be running any number of simultaneous other Lambdas at the same time as yours.  They aren't going to allow you to set a parameter that affects the entire VM for just your Lambda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least some JVM arguments can be passed via the **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** environment variable. I've used this successfully to debug classpath loading issues with the "-verbose:class" flag for example.

Comment: Anyone know the scope of this?  What arguments can be passed?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide VM parameters via a wrapper script (see [AWS Lambda Developer Guide - Wrapper scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-modify.html#runtime-wrapper)). The [following blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/increasing-performance-of-java-aws-lambda-functions-using-tiered-compilation/) shows how to do this for the `-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1` flags.